# How to use loop in R for big data set

Tags: r

Folks,
Today I have joined this community and I have a problem in using loop in R 
 My sample data set is as follows:-

```
Roll No     Marks
   1          60
   2          78
   3          84
```

I want a column to be added in this data set which will calculate grade of student.For eg If marks is more than 90 then A, 70-90 then B , less than 70 c.
I want my out as:-

```
Roll No       Marks     Grade
   1            60        C
   2            78        B
   3            84        B
```

Is it possible to do it In R using loop , because i have around 60 thousand of data

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Look at the `cut` function.

Comment: @ Ananda- can i use it for 60 thousand data sets

Comment: Um. Why not? 60K values is not that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `ifelse`, although using `cut` as suggested by @Ananda could be better

```
> transform(df, Grade= ifelse(Marks>90, "A", 
                              ifelse(Marks>=70 & Marks <=90, "B", "C")))
  Roll_No Marks Grade
1       1    60     C
2       2    78     B
3       3    84     B
```

Comment: @R.R `transform(df, Grade=cut(Marks, c(0,70,90,100), c("C", "B", "A")))` if you want to try it. Also, very generous grading scale.